# starforce won't fully install on windows 8

Tags: windows-8, drm

Recently I tried installing a game protected with StarForce protection drier, however after rebooting it always asks if I want to reboot to finish the installation of StarForce. 
clicking yes has no effect, the machine reboots but the game is unplayable because as soon as it's launched it asks to reboot to finish installing.
is there a way to bypass this driver installation so that the game can be played on windows 8?

Answer (score 1):

Use [SFREMOVE](http://www.star-force.com/support/sfdrvrem.zip) to remove the driver (if it is even installed) and then install the latest available driver with [SFUPDATE](http://www.star-force.com/support/sfdrvup.zip), as the latest version supports Windows 8, while many older versions do not.

You can also try using the [StarForce Helper Utility](http://www.star-force.com/support/sfhelper/).

Comment: if I install a newer version, will it be able to play a game that was protected with an older version of the driver?

Comment: @ZCoder I believe it should.